# Block my existing folder name and access with a custom folder name [htaccess]

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Simply I just want to hide my existing folder name, And access that folder and files with a custom name.
For example,
I have a folder named **old_folder**, and now I can access it with `https://example.com/old_folder`
But I want to block this URL. If someone browses this, The page should show an error message or custom page, if possible.

The folder and files inside the old folder should access with a custom name. Like `https://example.com/custom_folder`. If there will exist any file, `https://example.com/custom_folder/file1.jpg`

I tried,

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+old_folder(/\S*)?\s  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /custom_folder%1  [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^custom_folder(/.*)?$ old_folder$1  [L,NC]
```

It helps me to access `custom_folder` URL.
But still, if I use `old_folder` in the URL, it didn't block.

Comment: Please do add your tried htaccess rules file in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I added

Comment: Looks like you have contradictory statements in your question. First you said you want to block  `old_folder` but then you said you want to change its urls? Could you please clarify more on same, thank you.

Comment: In short, I just want to browse `/old_folder` with a custom URL `/custom_folder`. The folder will be the same name, but an error will appear when browsing the folder name (old_folder) directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you :

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+old_folder(/\S*)?\s  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ -  [F]
RewriteRule ^custom_folder(/.*)?$ old_folder$1  [L,NC]
```

This will show a forbidden error if the old folder name is entered in URLs while Your URLs will be accessible with `custom_folder` .

Comment: ++ for good answer. In first rule you can just use `[F]` instead of `[F,L,NE]`